# PHPCoord, MAMP Pro and Uncaught Error: Class

Tags: php, composer-php, coordinates, mamp

I am trying to use [PHPCoord](https://phpcoord.net/) to eventually convert coordinates stored in the Ordnance Survey National Grid reference system (OSGB) to Latitude and Longitude.

It looks like PHPCoord can do this, but I'm struggling to get it working.

I have successfully installed it within my local project using Composer.

However when I try and run the following [example](https://phpcoord.net/en/stable/coordinate_conversions_easy.html) bit of code (taken from the official docs):

```php
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Geographic2D;
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Projected;
use PHPCoord\GeographicPoint;
use PHPCoord\UnitOfMeasure\Angle\Degree;
$from = GeographicPoint::create(
    Geographic2D::fromSRID(Geographic2D::EPSG_NAD83),
    new Degree(28.46),
    new Degree(-80.53),
    null
);
$toCRS = Projected::fromSRID(Projected::EPSG_NAD83_FLORIDA_EAST);
$to = $from->convert($toCRS); // $to instanceof ProjectedPoint
```

I get the following errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GeographicPoint' not found...

> Error: Class 'GeographicPoint' not found

I'm using MAMP Pro and using the MAMP PHP (Version 7.4.12), composer is installed globally and php-coord has installed as expected within the local project in /vendor/php-coord.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you included the autoloader?

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, thanks for your help, not explicitly, do I need to something within the project? I read... 
> Composer will automatically take care of downloading the source and configuring an autoloader
And assumed it was sorted? Is there more I need to do?

Comment: As usual, you need to add `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'`  to your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris Haas and Nico Haase, I was nudged in the direction of Composer [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading). Being new to Composer and PHP libraries I had no idea I needed to do this.

As the vendor folder was within my WordPress theme I added the following to my header file:

```php
$theme_root = dirname(__DIR__, 1); // Header is an a sub directory so we need to move up a level
require_once $theme_root . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Which resolves this issue, I'm now getting errors of a different kind but I'll raise those as a different question.